# Neo4j computed relations

Tags: neo4j, relation, derived

Assume we have "marriage" objects with relations "spouse1" and "spouse2" to class "Person".
Is is possible in Neo4J to compute/derive a relation like (p1 -marriedTo -> p2) from the fact that there is a marriage object m with spouse1=p1 and spouse2=p2?

I did not find such a construct in Neo4J.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by define/compute? Do you want to visualize? To create a edge? To apply algo? For all these use cases tools are available.

Comment: I would like to have it available like a relation defined by a SQL VIEW. Storing it in the database is the 2nd best solution, but then I would have to maintain the computed links. I come from a deductive database background (ConceptBase.cc), where such expressions are super-easy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there is a node marriage with properties spouse1=p1 and spouse2=p2. If p1 and p2 are person ids (if p1,p2 are names, just change it to names and ensure it is unique), you can run below cypher to create the relationship :marriedTo from p1 to p2.

```
 MATCH (m: Marriage)
 WITH m.spouse1 as person1, m.spouse2 as person2
 MATCH (p1: Person {id: person1})
 WITH p1
 MATCH (p2: Person {id: person2})
 WITH p1, p2
 MERGE p=(p1) - [:marriedTo] - (p2)
 RETURN p
```

Comment: Many thanks, José! Would the fact "(p1) - [:marriedTo] - (p2)" be part of the database? I was looking for a solution similar to SQL views, where the facts in the view are derived from a query expression, rather than stored in the database.

Comment: There is no concept of a view in Graph Database.The connections (relationships) that you need must be created (or merged) beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, José. That is a pity. Having to store such relations means that one also has to maintain the stored links when the database changes. Seems that ConceptBase.cc is more powerful than Nei4j ...

Comment: Btw, it ConceptBase, one would define a simple rule "forall p1,p2/Person m/Marriage (m spouse1 p1) and (m spouse2 p2) ==> (p1 marriedTo p2)". And another rule would make it symmetric "forall p1,p2/Person (p1 marriedTo p2) ==> (p2 marriedTo p1)". Maybe, Neo4J could learn from this ....

Answer (score 0):

In case the pattern does not have to persist, the best way would be to use virtual relationships.

One way to do it is by using apoc : https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/
If you need to have further interaction with the visualized relationships, you may use other tooling, e.g. our [Graphileon](https://www.graphileon.com) platform (Disclosure :I work for the Graphileon team)

Comment: Thank! The virtual relationships are indeed what we were looking for. Our application is about traceability in engineering databases, where a vast number of artefacts are created depending on each other.